# How to determine if a list of string contains null or empty elements

Tags: java, string, collections

In Java, I have the following method:

```
public String normalizeList(List<String> keys) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to check that `keys`:

- Is not `null` itself; and
- Is not empty (`size() == 0`); and
- Does not have any `String` elements that are `null`; and
- Does not have any `String` elements that are empty ("")

This is a utility method that will go in a "commons"-style JAR (the class wil be something like `DataUtils`). Here is what I have, but I believe its incorrect:

```
public String normalize(List<String> keys) {
    if(keys == null || keys.size() == 0 || keys.contains(null) || keys.contains(""))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad!");

    // Rest of method...
}
```

I believe the last 2 checks for `keys.contains(null)` and `keys.contains("")` are incorrect and will likely thrown runtime exceptions. **I know I can just loop through the list inside the `if` statement, and check for nulls/empties there, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution if it exists.**

Comment: *"I believe the last 2 checks for keys.contains(null) and keys.contains("") are incorrect and will likely thrown runtime exceptions."*: Why? What exception do you expect?

Comment: keys.contains(null) will be fine however keys.contains("") will only work in certain situations but shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: Man, you have too many nulls flying around your app...

Comment: Doc says that NPE could be thrown. Anyway some implementations of `List` use `Collection#contains` make me sure to believe the docs.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
 keys.contains(null) || keys.contains("")
```

Doesn't throw any runtime exceptions and results `true` if your list has either null (or) empty String.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `List.contains` is allowed to throw `NullPointerException` if the list is not allowed to contain `null`. For example: `List.of("foo", "bar").contains(null)` will throw!

Comment: see my comment about org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils to resolve NullPointerException problem

Answer (score 8):

With java 8 you can do:

```
public String normalizeList(List<String> keys) {
    boolean bad = keys.stream().anyMatch(s -> (s == null || s.equals("")));
    if(bad) {
        //... do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( keys.stream().anyMatch(String::isBlank) ) { ...`. `String::isBlank` is since Java11.

Answer (score 7):

This looks fine to me, the only exceptions you would get from `keys.contains(null)` and `keys.contains("")` would be if `keys` itself was `null`.

However since you check for that first you know that at this point `keys` is not `null`, so no runtime exceptions will occur.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use [org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/current/api/org/springframework/util/CollectionUtils.html)
you can apply this

```
if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(coll) || CollectionUtils.containsInstance(coll, null)) {
        // throw ...;
}
```

It does not throw NullPointerException for immutable collection as List.of().

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but isn't there any helper class in ApacheCommon library to do that? like when you have the isEmpty for a string and you have isNullOrEmpty in ApacheCommons library

Answer (score 0):

Check the list in one pass

```
  public static boolean empty(String s) {
    if (s == null)
      return true;
    else if (s.length() == 0)
      return true;
    return false;
  }  

  public String normalize(List<String> keys) {
    if(keys == null || keys.size() == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad!");
    for (String key: keys)
      if(empty(key))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty!");

    // Rest of method...
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Apache StringUtils and check if the string isBlank, this will check for null, Emptystring and will also trim your value.

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(listItemString)){...}
```

Checkout StringUtils Docs here:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: This only works for one string not the whole list

Answer (score 0):

Aniket gave a really good answer for this as a comment:

```
if( keys.stream().anyMatch(String::isBlank) ) { .... String::isBlank is since Java11. – 
Aniket Sahrawat
Apr 6, 2019 at 2:30
```

So to tweak your original solution using Aniket's comment:

```
public String normalize(List<String> keys) {
    if(keys == null || keys.size() == 0  || keys.stream().anyMatch(String::isBlank)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad!");
    }

    // Rest of method...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean badListInRequest = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(request.getIdList()) ||
                request.getIdList().stream().anyMatch(s -> (StringUtils.isBlank(s)));

if(badListInRequest){
    throw new Exception...
}
```